# MS-Access Debug Watch value length is limited

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working in MS-Access 2010 and I am trying to view a variable defined in the VBA code where it has hit a break-point. The problem in the watch window the value text box in the Watches window has a set size, in other words if the value is to long the value is cut-off in the Watches window

How can I view the whole value inside my variable?

Comment: Have you tried using `Debug.Print variable_name_here` in the immediate window?

Comment: or simply `?variablename` on immediate window.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is best to use the intermediate window for this. I frequently do this with SQL queries for this reason.

To show this, use "View--> Intermediate Window" (or Control+G).

Then use syntax like the following:

```
debug.print "This is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long stringThis is a really long string"
```

And you can select and copy/paste out of the intermediate window or scroll to see the whole variable.

Note that the intermediate window does not get cleared automatically but you can select everything and delete it whenever you want.

Comment: For those who don't know it's "immediate window", at least in Access 2016. Thanks for the tip!